# Is QuickBlox supports Huawei devices or not?

Tags: quickblox, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, quickblox-android, huawei-push-notification

As [QuickBlox](https://quickblox.com/) is using Firebase and Huawei devices are not supporting Firebase now. Is there any way to use QuickBlox SDK on Huawei devices or not?
Or is there any other SDK that I can use in place of QuickBlox?

Comment: hi@Faizan, I've posted my answers below. by the way may i ask which country are you from? Also could you pls leave your email address, then we can let local colleague to get in touch with you

Comment: I am from Pakistan.
My email address is: m.faizanahmad12@gmail.com

Comment: hi@Faizan, Our colleague said that he has received your tickets, you can send your app information to him in the tickets.

Answer (score 0):

According to the team, the QuickBlox SDK currently does not support Huawei devices by now.

The following links are some 3rd party platforms with huawei Push supported for your reference:

[Airship](https://www.airship.com/) : [Docs](https://docs.airship.com/platform/android/getting-started/#hms)

[Braze](https://www.braze.com/): [Docs](https://www.braze.com/docs/developer_guide/platform_integration_guides/android/push_notifications/android/integration/huawei_integration/?redirected=true)

[MoEngage](https://www.moengage.com/) : [Docs](https://docs.moengage.com/docs/dashboard-configuring-huawei-push)

[OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) : [Docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/huawei-sdk-setup)